# How do I make JQgrid td height fixed in case of vertically overflowing content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I use the following code:

```
loadComplete: function (data) {
  $('.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td').each(function () {
  var htmlString = $(this).html();
  htmlString = '<div class=\'divJqgridMaxHeight\'>' + htmlString+ '</div>';            
  $(this).html(htmlString);
});
```

This fixes the problem but only for read-only grids, for editable grids this causes issues.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to change the following css class in ui.jqgrid.css :

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
 /*some css*/
 max-height: 20px;
}
```

simply change height to max-height.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Goks for the answer but i tried this before.After applying this CSS for overflow tr.jqgrow td content height will increase.

Comment: Hi Samal, maybe you can explain What Kind of problem do you have??